# Complex SQL Query in JOIN

Tags: sql, database, db2

**Tables**

```
TRANSACTIONS

SUPP_ID   |  PAYMENT
----------+----------
  1001         200
  1002         100
  1005         250

MASTER_SUPPLIERS

SUPP_ID   |   AREA
----------+----------
  1001         ABC
  1002         XYZ
  1003         TYU
  1004         MNO
  1005         PQR
```

**Intention:**
Find those count of suppliers area wise where no payment (`NO_TRANS_CNT`) has been received

```
SELECT AREA, COUNT(*) AS NO_TRANS_CNT FROM MASTER_SUPPLIERS
WHERE AREA NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(AREA) FROM TRANSACTIONS)
GROUP BY AREA

 AREA     | NO_TRANS_CNT
----------+--------------
  TYU           1
  MNO           1
```

**Want to ask:** Now, I also want to add the column `TOTAL_SUPPLIERS` in this area

```
  AREA     | TOTAL SUPPLIERS   |  NO_TRANS_CNT
----------+--------------------+----------------
  ABC              1                  0   
  XYZ              1                  0   
  TYU              1                  1                 
  MNO              1                  1
  PQR              1                  0
```

I think it can be achieved using JOINs, but I am not able to get how ?

Comment: Quick and dirty: use your existing query as a subquery, left join it back to your table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  M.AREA
, COUNT(1) TOTAL_SUPPLIERS
, COUNT(CASE WHEN T.SUPP_ID IS NULL THEN 1 END) NO_TRANS_CNT
FROM MASTER_SUPPLIERS M
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON T.SUPP_ID = M.SUPP_ID
GROUP BY M.AREA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select M.AREA, COUNT(*) as TOTAL_SUPPLIERS, COUNT(T.PAYMENT) as NO_TRANS_CNT
from MASTER_SUPPLIERS M left join TRANSACTIONS T
     on M.SUPP_ID = T.SUPP_ID
group by M.AREA;
```

could work.
Note that the COUNT(T.PAYMENT) only counts those where the PAYMENT is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join`, but start with `suppliers`:

```
select ms.area, count(*) as num_suppliers, count(t.supp_id) as num_transactions
from master_suppliers ms left join
     transactions t
     on t.supp_id = m.supp_id
group by ms.area;
```

The `left join` keeps everything in the *first* table -- which is what you want, along with matching rows from the second.

When you count the number of transactions, the argument to `count()` should either be a column used in the `on` clause or the primary key.